# How to display a picture in Python

Tags: python

I have run 
    easy_install pygame
    easy_install xdot
in command window, and it says pygame and xdot have been installed, however, when I run the following code,

```
from coinor.gimpy import Graph
import pygame 

if __name__=='__main__':    
    g = Graph()
    g.add_edge(0,1)
    g.add_edge(1,2)
    g.add_edge(3,4)
    g.set_display_mode('xdot')
    g.display()
```

it has some error:

```
Error: xdot not installed. Display disabled.
```

and when I changed the mode xdot to pygame,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Code\Eclipse\IE411HW1\problem1.py", line 11, in <module>
g.display()
  File "E:\learning software\Python\lib\site-packages\coinor.gimpy-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\coinor\gimpy\graph.py", line 1625, in display
im = StringIO.StringIO(self.create(self.get_layout(), format))
  File "E:\learning software\Python\lib\site-packages\coinor.gimpy-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\coinor\gimpy\graph.py", line 1559, in create
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "E:\learning software\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "E:\learning software\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]
```

How can I debug? I was working for a couple of hours and still can't figure out how to display a graph! Thank you.

Comment: Is that your full code, are you importing anything?

Comment: What was the issue? How did you solve it?

Comment: OK here means I modified the code in this post, it is incomplete, as you said, I am missing something. I haven't solved my problem yet....

Answer (score 0):

WindowsError: [Error 2] tells you that "The system cannot find the file specified."

It looks like the error is with:

```
from coinor.gimpy import Graph
```

Try removing it/checking that the installation is there?

Comment: if I remove g.display(), it runs well, so I think the error is probably not caused by from coinor.gimpy import Graph

Comment: To use pygame you must have this line : pygame.init()

Comment: unfortunitely, no, error---pygame.error: Couldn't open ball.bmp, what's the problem here? How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: You need that file w/e your pygame file is. Just create one in paint. Make it small.

Comment: it worked by popping out a window and the ball is moving quickly~

Comment: So this versify that your Pygame is installed and working. What is the exact error you get when running your code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46293/discussion-between-user3029108-and-user2100799)